# Laravel 8: routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is it possible in Laravel 8 not to specify routing for methods in the class, that is, so that they work automatically?

Let's say there is a class `CreateController`
and methods

```
function doc() {...}

function pdf() {...}

function xls() {...}
```

That is, when accessing url at an address of the form **site.com/create/doc** it worked out the method `doc` of the class `CreateController`

Or there is no such possibility and you will have to register a route for each method, that is

```
Route::get('/create/doc', 'CreateController@doc');
Route::get('/create/pdf', 'CreateController@pdf');
Route::get('/create/xls', 'CreateController@xls');
...
```

Comment: Try a for loop?

Comment: Route::get('/create/{type}', 'CreateController@create'); passing the type to the create function could be alternative way

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in the second string parameter, but if you make this parameter a callback function:

```php
Route::get('/create/{type}', function(string $type) {
    return (new CreateController)->{$type}();
})->where('type', 'doc|pdf|xls');
```

If you want to allow all methods as type and keep it dynamic so that you can add to or remove from the controller without editing the routes:

```php
$class = new ReflectionClass(CreateController::class);
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
Route::get('/create/{type}', function(string $type) {
    return (new CreateController)->{$type}();
})->where('type', implode('|', $methods));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for meIn the first example, 
you need to use "use App\Http\Controllers\CreateController;" otherwise there will be an error Class 'CreateController' not found

Comment: @СергейБарахтенко Yes you should import it , or put a backslash \CreateController